# Как парсить parimatch python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста! Не могу никак нормально пропарсить верхний столбик в паримач. Пробывал xpath парсер день работает потом выдает ошибку(полагаю динамически меняется html)
Мне нужно вытащить результат п1 и п2, имя и время!

Вот мой код, буду благодарен кто его модтфицирует и подскажет как делать не надо

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
import time
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 
driver.get('https://parimatch.com/ru/table-tennis')
time.sleep(4)
 
block = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_2c98cYcZ15eCL3kXBibIh_')[:1]
for item in block:
    name = item.find_element_by_class_name('_26B_f8qfrQUqtdUjGVw3dk').text
    time = item.find_element_by_class_name('_1LmvJKRD8MAsF3wKlXcsgF').text[9:]
    p1 = item.find_element_by_class_name('_3Sa1tkZVXvesvtPRE_cUEV').text
    p2w = item.find_elements_by_class_name('_3Sa1tkZVXvesvtPRE_cUEV')[1:]
    for i in p2w:
        p2 = i.text
 
        info = []
        if float(p1) > 1.83 and float(p1) < 1.90:
            if float(p2) > 1.83 and float(p2) < 1.90:
                result = {"times": time, "name": name, "p1": p1, "p2": p2, }
                info.append(result)
 
        print(info)
```

Comment: Хм, у моего провайдера этот сайт вообще заблокирован. Что это за сайт? %)

Comment: Это сайт ставок на спорт, и он в Росии правда заблокирован.